# compilation issue with execute immediate in Forall statement

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, bulkinsert, dynamic-sql

Please help me in resolving below issue i am facing, i have to insert data into a table(table name genereted using variable value and table is created already) within FORALL..

```
Declare
TYPE dept_data_rec IS RECORD
(
  Dept_no number,
  Dept_name varchar2(100),
  Dept_loc  Varchar2(20)
 );

TYPE nt_dept_data IS TABLE OF dept_data_rec ;

l_dept_data_nt nt_dept_data;

BEGIN

FORALL j IN 1..l_dept_data_nt.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO '||l_get_dept_rec.dept_seq_no||'_Dept_Data  VALUES '||
l_dept_data_nt(j);
COMMIT;
```

while compiling this code i am getting below error:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

However when code using actual table name it works

```
FORALL j IN 1..l_dept_data_nt.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
INSERT INTO A1_dept_data VALUES
l_dept_data_nt(j);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Right. `l_dept_data_nt(j)` is a row type or record type; you can only concatenate a string, or something that can be cast to a string. I don't think you can use a bind variable to do that, even if it's defined as `%rowtype`, but I'm not 100% sure. You might need to look at `dbms_sql`. Someone might have a better idea though *8-)

Comment: Thanks..i feel the problem is with l_dept_data_nt(j), i am trying below as well however same error msg coming.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO A1_dept_DATA VALUES '||l_dept_data_nt(j);

Comment: Please provide declaration of `l_dept_data_nt`. Seems to be a collection. The question is are elements of that collection of scalar or composite data type?

Comment: Hi Nic, declaration added in code section

Comment: The documentation is unclear as to whether you can or can't "change" tables per row with FORALL. I would assume not as this would result in 0 performance benefit (purely syntactical benefit).

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle 10g -**

In versions of Oracle prior to 11g, you can't use `FORALL` with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, only with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems021.htm

It's a special syntax

1. that reads like a FOR loop but isn't, and
2. is used by PL/SQL to perform bulked DML operations and only with the exact keyword, not with dynamic SQL or any other code.

**Oracle 11g +**

In 11g, the restriction on using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` was lifted. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/forall_statement.htm

However, the only variables allowed in the string are subscripted elements from a single array in the `USING` clause.

The documentation is unclear whether you can dynamically "change" the table per row using the `FORALL` syntax. Remember that the `FORALL` is used by PL/SQL to perform a bulk DML operation and that needs to go to one table for this to yield any performance benefit.

**Best performance solution for the above problem**

You should make two levels of arrays, the first defines which table and the second defines the data for that table.

Use an ordinary `FOR` loop over the table array and inside that loop use the special `FORALL` syntax to perform all the DML for the one table.

Comment: The documentation is unclear whether the single table restriction is actually enforced or whether this silently just results in reduced performance!